# controller taking lot of time causing time out

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a code like this

```
def validate

  if abc.nil?
    redirect_to :action => 'noInitialSelection'
  else
    redirect_to :action => 'Selection'
    script(params)
  end

end
```

The script method has to process a file of 10000 names and do related work . now the problem is as it takes a lot of time for the code to be completed , the page is not being redirected to selection and causing a 500 internal server error

i want the page to be redirected to 'selection' so that the user knows he has entered correct details and then do the script method in the background

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into a job queue to run the `script(params)`. There are multiple gems for this; a very popular one is **[delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)**.

Once you setup delayed_job, your method might look like

```
def validate
  if abc.nil?
    redirect_to :action => 'noInitialSelection'
  else
    Delayed::Job.enqueue ScriptJob.new(params)
    redirect_to :action => 'Selection'
  end
end
```

You would independently create a custom job like

```
class ScriptJob < Struct.new(:params)
  def perform
    script(params)
  end
end
```

The `enqueue` call queues the `script(params)` into the job queue for processing by a worker.